# How to get configuration value from default

Tags: configuration, system-config, core-config-data, system-configuration

I want to get a config value from core_config but the default level 
I know we can get it by using scope config but I want default

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('example_section/general/field_data', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

When you give SCOPE_STORE it will give you default value

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at this and test it out